# Best way to check for near objects in SQL database according to x and y columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with pretty static objects e.g buildings with x and y coorinates for a game in which I will be sending http requests to my server to get all objects around some given x and y coordinates.

Currently I am using this simple sql on the server which then returns the data in JSON.

```
SELECT OBJECTS.id \"id\", POINTS.x, POINTS.y 
FROM OBJECT, OBJECTPOINTS, POINTS 
WHERE OBJECTPOINTS.OID = OBJECTS.ID AND OBJECTPOINTS.PID = POINTS.ID AND 
ABS(POINTS.x -\"+x+") < 0.01 AND ABS(POINTS.y - "+y+") < 0.01;"
```

Each object is represented by points which will be used to draw on the client.

I am currently achieving ~ 5 seconds respond time for around 1.5M Points and 200k objects.
To me this is fairly reasonable however the problem I have is that the db is blocked with each request. Here are 10 requests sent at the same time

:[image]

36 seconds for map data with 10 clients requesting at the same time is way too much. 
So my question is what would be a better way to handle the request rather then comparing distance in sql?

Would it be deliberatly faster to hold all of those objects in memory and iterate them on the server?

I have also thought of abstracting all the data in to some kind of grid and then first checking in which grid the request coords are to then run the same query as above on the db with only the objects in that certain square. Is there some clever solution I might be overlooking in the sql maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query cannot be utilized by an index, because you are using a function on your column data in the `where`-clause of your query (`ABS(POINTS.x ...)`). If you rewrite your query to compare the raw value of your columns against another value you can add an index to your table and your query no longer needs to scan your full table to answer the query.

Rewrite your `where` clause to something like this to replace the `ABS()` function.

```
(POINTS.x < (x + 0.01) AND POINTS.x > (x - 0.01))
```

Then add an index to your table like:

```
alter table POINTS add index position(x, y);
```

Check the changing of the scanned rows of both queries with and without the index by adding the `explain` keyword infront of your query.

Comment: So I did what you said and now it takes 3 times longer. Im getting 10 seconds for the first request. Is an index not the solution or is my query the  problem? EDIT: FORGIVE ME. I left out the y check, dumb me. Am now at 200ms AWESOME!.

Comment: you're welcome. The index is pretty much doing the "grid check" for you.